# Different using by Condition in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Imagine following view:

```
@if(Model.Condition)
{
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(...))
    {
        //MyForm
    }
}
else
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm(...))
    {
        //MyForm
    }
}
```

Is it possible to combine this two usings based on a condition, without writing `//MyForm` twice?

Comment: Try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, by assigning it to a variable and `using()` that:

```
@{
    IDisposable form;

    if(Model.Condition)
    {
        form = Ajax.BeginForm(...);    
    }
    else
    {
        form = Html.BeginForm(...);
    }
}

using (form)
{
    // Form here
}
```

Or you could just use an EditorTemplate to prevent writing the form's contents twice:

```
@if(Model.Condition)
{
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(...))
    {
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    }
}
else
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm(...))
    {
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the input :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could just use this

```
@using (Model.Condition ? Ajax.BeginForm() : Html.BeginForm())
{
    //MyForm
}
```

Comment: Oh this works fine. Thank you. Didn't know that the ternary operator also works here.